# Counting words in a file using Counter Object

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, counter

I have two python files to count the words and frequency

```
import io
import collections
import codecs
from collections import Counter

with io.open('JNb.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as infh:
    words = infh.read().split()
    with open('e1.txt', 'a') as f:
        for word, count in Counter(words).most_common(10):
            f.write(u'{} {}\n'.format(word, count).encode('utf8'))
```

---

```
import io
import collections
import codecs
from collections import Counter

with io.open('JNb.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as infh:
    for line in infh:
        words =line.split()
        with open('e1.txt', 'a') as f:
            for word, count in Counter(words).most_common(10):
                f.write(u'{} {}\n'.format(word, count).encode('utf8'))
```

None of the provides output.

The code contains no syntax error.

Output

```
താത്കാലിക 1
- 1
ഒഴിവ് 1
അധ്യാപക 1
വാര്‍ത്തകള്‍ 1
ആലപ്പുഴ 1
ഇന്നത്തെപരിപാടി 1
വിവാഹം 1
അമ്പലപ്പുഴ 1
```

The actual file contains 100 occurrence of these words.

I am not printing anything, I am writing all to a file(`e1`)

Update: I tried another one and got result

```
import collections
import codecs
from collections import Counter

    with io.open('JNb.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as infh:
        words =infh.read().split()
        with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f:
            for word, count in Counter(words).most_common(10000000):
                f.write(u'{} {}\n'.format(word, count).encode('utf8'))
```

It can count up to 2 GB files in 4Gb RAM

What is the problem here?

Comment: What output? Both write the result to the file `e1.txt`.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't appear to work for you, but your code has improved a lot since you first starting asking about this subject! :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters With your help :)

Comment: @It is producing wrong output

Comment: @karu Same output of two code snippet?

Comment: @lake9m Yes, I am getting same

Comment: The reason your last version uses so much memory is the inf.read().split() call, which loads the entire file into memory, and then splits it into words. Try reading the file line by line and splitting each line into words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I coded up the task and here is my solution.

I have tested the program with a 5.1 GB text file. The program finished in ~20 minutes on a MBP6.2.

Let me know if there are any confusions or suggestions. Best of luck.

```
from collections import Counter
import io
import sys

cnt = Counter()

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Provide an input file as argument")
    sys.exit()

try:
    with io.open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                cnt[word] += 1
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")

with sys.stdout as f:
    total_word_count = sum(cnt.values())
    for word, count in cnt.most_common(30):
        f.write('{: < 6} {:<7.2%} {}\n'.format(
            count, count / total_word_count, word))
```

Output:

```
~ python countword.py CSW07.txt 
 79619 4.58%   [n]
 63717 3.67%   a
 56783 3.27%   of
 42341 2.44%   to
 40156 2.31%   the
 39295 2.26%   [v]
 38231 2.20%   [n
 36592 2.11%   -S]
 35250 2.03%   or
 17113 0.98%   in
```

Comment: @brnsgaard, my file is too big

Comment: @karu How big is your file? Is it possible for you to share it?

Comment: 3.85 Gb,in processed in raw it is 8 Gb

Comment: @karu, That is also a crazy big file, can you share it somehow? And what do you mean by 'my file is too big'? Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: How you keep track of words ? like you have one in first line and another word in at the end of the file. How you count that one ?

Comment: @brunsgaard55, How you count a word that at first line and at last line? What will be the count of particular words according to your algorithm ?

Comment: @karu, I am sorry, but I do not understand what you mean! Could you paraphrase your question, please make an effort to write readable english, otherwise I do not have a chance.

By the way, I tested my program on a 5 gigabyge text file. It took ~20 minutes to finish, but got the job done :)

Comment: @brunsgaard55, Still give some Unicode based errors, But your program is fine working perfectly

Comment: Ok, maybe the file is then encoded in another format, you have to supply me with an exmaple input file that lead to the exceptions if I am to help you further.

Comment: @burnsgaard താത്കാലിക 1
- 1
ഒഴിവ് 1
അധ്യാപക 1
വാര്‍ത്തകള്‍ 1
ആലപ്പുഴ

Answer (score 0):

You are counting words for each line.
Maybe try to read whole file, split by words, and make the Counter call.

Edit: If you don't have enough memory for read all file but enough for store all different words:

```
import io
import collections
import codecs
from collections import Counter

def count(file):
    f = open(file,'r') 
    cnt = Counter()
    for line in f.readlines():
        words = line.split(" ")
        for word in words:
            cnt[word] += 1
    f.close()
    return cnt
```

Now get the counter return and print to file the data you want.

Comment: @laste, I can´t read  whole file to memory, because of huge size of file

Comment: Ok, maybe you can mention it in your post.

Comment: @karu instead of `infh.read().split()`, read line-by-line, e.g. `for line in infh: ...` or `infh.readline().rsplit()`

Comment: If the volume of file is very high...it's a classic mapreduce algorithm what you need.

Comment: @karu Have you memory enough for store all different words? if you don't you can't do it in a single machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read each line, split it into words, and then update the counter. Otherwise you are only counting each line separately. Even if the file is very big, since you are only storing the individual words, you will be processing it line-by-line.

Try this version instead:

```
import collections
import io

c = collections.defaultdict(int)

with io.open('somefile.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   for line in f:
       if len(line.strip()):
           for word in line.split(' '):
               c[word] += 1

with io.open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    for word, count in c.iteritems():
        f.write('{} {}\n'.format(word, count))
```